# CSS - Two floating divs in same line, one with wrapping text

Tags: css, css-float

Here's the problem:
I want to have 2 floating divs in same line. Right div could be fixed width. Left div should take all remainig space, and wrap text inside. Parent container width is variable, so I can't set width on both divs.

http://jsfiddle.net/af6wP/

```
div{border: 1px solid black}
.left{float: left}
.right{float: right}
<div class="left">
    very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text 
</div>

<div class="right">
    short text
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like you need only one float here:

```
div{border: 1px solid black}
.left{ overflow: hidden; }
.right{float: right}
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/KmPjL/

Comment: This is an effective solution which needs no special styling of the parent element.  Just the left and right floating divs.  It is important to add the right-floating element as the first one to the HTML DOM and the main left element with very long text as the second.  I [commented on the original fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prantlf/Tmd7u/).

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Got a better solution for a fixed width on the right div :

**Html**

```
<div class="left">
    <div class="right">
        short text
    </div>
    very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text 

</div>
```

**Css**

```
div{border: 1px solid black;}
.right{float:right;width:24%;}
```

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/soyuka/af6wP/5/)

With a long text on the right container, you'll have to use a [clearfix](http://pastebin.com/dyVHk8Ax).